# Is there a special way to set up Garry's Mod for Mac?

Tags: steam, macos, garrys-mod

I just downloaded Garry's Mod from Steam and every time I try to play Single Player on the first map, it crashes on the Loading Resources section of the progress bar.

Here is some of the exception information the system prints out:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000001acec4d0
Crashed Thread:  4
```

When I ran it on the Windows side (Bootcamp), Windows 7 required me to give Garry's Mod some permissions. I wasn't asked to do this on the Mac side. Maybe that's it?

Is there some kind of special setup for the Mac?

Comment: That sounds like a software bug to be honest, rather than something you can troubleshoot away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the latest [GMod update](http://www.garrysmod.com/2011/03/02/update-114-released/#disqus_thread), broke the Mac version.

I would suggest waiting for a update, that fixes it.

Comment: Ah. Okay. Looks like I chose a bad day to download it for the first time.

Comment: If you really want to try it, maybe you could be able to make it work by cleaning all games files, then reDL it after unticking the "automatically download update for this game" tickbox in game options. That way, you should be able to download an unpatched version, which does not include the problematic update.